# InApp Purchase in windows phone c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

i submit the beta version on store and make a product list..
accoridng to this link

[enter link description here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/in-app-purchasing-for-windows-phone-8.aspx)

```
  //StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        var listing=await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        foreach (var product in listing.ProductListings)
        {
           sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}, {4}",
                product.Key,
                product.Value.Name,
                product.Value.FormattedPrice,
                product.Value.ProductType,
                product.Value.Description));
        }
       MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "List all products", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

Exception is :Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EE7

how can i slove?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this exception in a App directly downloaded from Store or in a debug version you deployed manually?

If it is a debug version, make sure the correct ProductId is used in WMAppManifest.xml (from store, if the App is already published).

If you are yet to publish the App to store, the only option you have is to test with [CurrentAppSimulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator) and change it back to CurrentApp just before publishing (and keep your fingers crossed).

Also remember, the call to LoadListingInformationAsync() method can throw exception for various reasons, including network failures. So it is always a good idea to wrap this method call with a Try/Catch block.